# What is the purpose of the ColorModel() method in the image.Image interface?

Tags: go

Go's `image.Image` interface has three methods: `Bounds` (clearly necessary for determining the size of an image), `At` (which returns the actual color at each pixel), and `ColorModel`. This last method returns a `color.Model`, which is capable of converting a color from any model into the representation that this image uses.

Why is `ColorModel` a part of this interface? How is it used by consumers of the `image.Image` type? If I have an image `img`, and I know nothing about its underlying representation, what good does `img.ColorModel()` do me? I can convert any color into the proper model, but I don't see what I can use this converted color for; the other two ways of interacting with an image, `At` and `Bounds`, do not take colors as arguments.

Am I missing something? Do any standard library functions call the `ColorModel` method of an `image.Image`, and what for?

Comment: How would set a color in your image if you couldn't convert your color to the correct model?

Comment: How would you determine the color model if the image would not provide this information?

Comment: @JimB In general, you can't set a color in the image. None of the interface methods support changing a color, and not all images are stored as mutable arrays of colors.

Comment: @Volker Hmm, what do you need to determine the color model for? color.Color is an interface with a method for converting to RGBA. And in general, "knowing a color model" just means having a way to convert an arbitrary color into that color model (color.Model is an interface with a single method for conversion). What good is it to be able to convert?

Comment: @AlexLew: yup, forgot that `Set` calls convert regardless, since I rarely ever use `At` and `Set`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question entirely, but I do not think the purpose of ColorModel() is to change the color. It is only to get the color model.

The standard library uses it mostly when encoding images, like in the png package:

```
switch m.ColorModel() {
case color.GrayModel:
    e.cb = cbG8
case color.Gray16Model:
    e.cb = cbG16
case color.RGBAModel, color.NRGBAModel, color.AlphaModel:
    if opaque(m) {
        e.cb = cbTC8
    } else {
        e.cb = cbTCA8
    }
default:
    if opaque(m) {
        e.cb = cbTC16
    } else {
        e.cb = cbTCA16
    }
}
```

Another hint on it's intended use can be found in the jpeg/writer:

```
// TODO(wathiede): switch on m.ColorModel() instead of type.
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. I guess it still seems misleading to me to say that you return a color.Model, an interface, when consumers actually compare your returned object to a predefined set of existing objects. But I can see that there might not be a better way to arrange things, given Go's lack of, e.g., tagged union types.

Comment: Hope it's OK to ask one follow-up! Why is this approach (switching on the return value of the ColorModel() method) more desirable than using a type-switch on the color returned by the `At` method?

Comment: I think the primary reason will be speed. The type switch is slower.
For a simple benchmark: https://play.golang.org/p/bocw3y9RHS

I also think it looks stylistically nicer to get the ColorModel directly instead of first getting some pixel's color and then checking the type of that.

Both would work though.

Answer (score 1):

To extend the accepted answer:

Although the `color.Model` is capable of converting a color to a different color type, as said in [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image):

> Interface `ColorModel` describes the image's color model.

i.e. it's not the pixel's color model. It looks similar, but the latter implies that an image *may* contain pixel(s) with a different color model.

Note that an `image` represents a rectangular grid of homogeneous colors, i.e. all pixels have the same color model. Once you understand the *color model* of an `image`, it's better and more efficient to cast the `image` to a particular concrete image type, then work directly on that particular image. The following snippet illustrates the idea:

```
switch img.ColorModel() {
case color.RGBAModel:
    // Try to cast to RGBA first
    m, ok := img.(*image.RGBA)
    if !ok {
        //not an RGBA image, do generic/custom processing,
        //e.g. using interface exposed by image.Image
        return
    }
    
    //Direct pixel access for performance
    for y := m.Rect.Min.Y; y < m.Rect.Max.Y; y++ {
        yp := (y - m.Rect.Min.Y) * m.Stride
        for x := m.Rect.Min.X; x < m.Rect.Max.X; x++ {
            rgba := m.Pix[yp+(x-m.Rect.Min.X)*4:] //[]byte{r, g, b, a}
            //get rgba component
            r, g, b, a := rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]
            
            //set r channel to RED
            rgba[0] = 255
            
            //...           
        }
    }
}
```

is more efficient compared to the following code

```
// Less efficient image processing
// a type-switch on the color returned by the `At` method
b := img.Bounds()
for y := b.Min.Y; y < b.Max.Y; y++ {
    for x := b.Min.X; x < b.Max.X; x++ {
        col := img.At(x, y)
        switch col := col.(type) {
        case color.RGBA:
            //do something with pixel
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's strange to me to do that, though, because an image can have an RGBA color model without being an `image.RGBA`. I've implemented my own image types that represent, say, graphs of functions, and contain no array of pixel values; the color model is still RGBA because I return RGBA colors from `At`, but anyone trying to do a type coercion will be disappointed. (In general, if your goal is to do a type coercion, why not just do it and see if it works? Why check a color model first?)

Comment: You're correct that the image having `color.RGBAModel` not necessarily an `image.RGBA`. My main point is, do the type check **outside** the loop instead of of doing it *inside* the loop every time you got a color by `At` method. It's expensive. Perhaps, for small image, the difference is unnoticeable, but when dealing with large images (3D/4D images), you will see the difference.  If it's not an RGB image, you can always fallback to *generic* inefficient access mode. I've updated the answer to reflect my comment.

Comment: Thanks, your point is well-taken! It seems to me that `ColorModel` doesn't really factor into this, though; you can do the type coercion (of the entire image) outside the loop without using `ColorModel` at all, and if you care about efficiency, you _should_ do this, as the call to `ColorModel` is extraneous and potentially misleading.